# "takeWhile" within a list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, list-comprehension, infinite

I have something like the following:

```
[bla z|n<-[0..], let z = foo n, z < 42]
```

The thing is, I want the list comprehension to end as soon as `z < 42` fails, as if it were a takeWhile. I know I could refactor this into a bunch of filters and maps, but it will be much more elegant with a list comprehension.

What is the most elegant way to combine list comprehensions and takeWhile?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't syntax sugar for a `takeWhile` for list comprehensions.  However, if you were to use `map` and `takeWhile`, it'd come out as `map bla $ takeWhile (< 42) $ map foo [0..]`, which I don't see as particularly inelegant.

Comment: You could do something like `[bla z | z <- takeWhile (< 42) [foo n | n <- [0..]]`, this keeps things much more list-comprehension-y.

Answer (score 6):

Since list comprehensions do not allow this, I have hacked a bit using *monad* comprehensions and defining a custom monad. The outcome of that is that the following works:

```
example :: [Int]
example = toList [1000 + n 
                 | n <- fromList [0..]
                 , _ <- nonStopGuard (n > 1)
                 , let z = 10*n
                 , _ <- stopGuard (z < 42) ]

-- Output: [1002,1003,1004]
```

The above works as a normal list comprehension, but has two different kinds of guard. A `nonStopGuard` works as a regular guard, except for requiring a bizarre syntax. A `stopGuard` instead does something more: as soon as it become false, it stops further choices in the *previous* generators (such as `<-[0..]`) to be considered.

The small library I wrote is shown below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, MonadComprehensions #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

data F a = F [a] Bool
  deriving (Functor, Show)
```

The `Bool` above is a *stop* bit, signaling we must *stop* considering further choices.

```
instance Applicative F where pure = return; (<*>) = ap
instance Monad F where
   return x = F [x] False
   F [] s      >>= _ = F [] s
   F (x:xs) sx >>= f = F (ys ++ zs) (sx || sy || sz)
      where 
      F ys sy = f x
      F zs sz = if sy then F [] False else F xs sx >>= f
```

The last `if` will discard the `xs` part when `f x` signals to stop.

```
nonStopGuard :: Bool -> F ()
nonStopGuard True  = F [()] False
nonStopGuard False = F []   False
```

A regular guard never signals to stop. It just provides one or zero choices.

```
stopGuard :: Bool -> F ()
stopGuard True  = F [()] False
stopGuard False = F [] True
```

A stopping guard instead signals to stop as soon as it becomes false.

```
fromList :: [a] -> F a
fromList xs = F xs False

toList :: F a -> [a]
toList (F xs _) = xs
```

Last caveat: I'm not completely sure my monad instance defines an actual monad, i.e. whether it satisfies the monad laws.

---

Following the suggestion of @icktoofay, I wrote a few quickcheck tests:

```
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (F a) where
   arbitrary = F <$> arbitrary <*> arbitrary

instance Show (a -> b) where
   show _ = "function"

prop_monadRight :: F Int -> Bool
prop_monadRight m =
   (m >>= return) == m

prop_monadLeft :: Int -> (Int -> F Int) -> Bool
prop_monadLeft x f =
   (return x >>= f) == f x

prop_monadAssoc :: F Int -> (Int -> F Int) -> (Int -> F Int) -> Bool
prop_monadAssoc m f g =
   ((m >>= f) >>= g)
   ==
   (m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g))
```

Running 100000 tests found no counterexamples. So, it's likely that the above `F` is an actual monad.

Comment: You might be able to use QuickCheck to test to see if `F` is a `Monad` if you implement `Arbitrary` for it.

Comment: That's completely nuts. +1.

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks, I just tried your suggestion. No counterexamples after 100000 tests.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a good answer for this, so I'll just suggest a kludge that lets you use as much of the list comprehension as possible:

```
map snd . takeWhile fst $
    [(z < 42, bla z)|n<-[0..], let z = foo n]
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good point to stop using list comprehensions and instead learn to work with higher-order list functions, such as the ones provided in [the `Data.List` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html).

Fundamentally, list comprehensions are just a pretty syntax for nested uses of `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`.  So your original comprehension:

```
[bla z|n<-[0..], let z = foo n, z < 42]
```

...is really the same as this:

```
let step n = let z = foo n
             in if z < 42 then [] else [bla z] 
in concatMap step [0..]
```

But the idiomatic way of writing comprehension-like computations directly is with `map`, `filter` and the `Applicative` class (the last of which is not needed in this one example):

```
map bla (filter (<42) (map foo [0..]))
```

And once you have it written like this, it's easy to see that this is what you want:

```
map bla (takeWhile (<42) (map foo [0..]))
```