# Haskell - Why does this list comprehension return an infinite list?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

```
[3 * x | x <- [1 ..], 3 * x < 20]
```

I don't really understand why this gives

```
[3,6,9,12,15,18
```

And doesn't find an end

Comment: How do you know there's not a number _really_ far down the list `[1 ..]` that doesn't satisfy your condition?  After all, what if you changed `[1 ..]` to `([1 .. 100000] ++ [2])`?  Or what if you had a numeric type that "wrapped around" so that when it got super high, it became low again?  GHC certainly doesn't know, so it's going to keep on trying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The semantics of

```
[3 * x | x <- [1 ..], 3 * x < 20]
```

is to try all the elements of `[1..]` and keep those satisfying the filter condition `3*x<20`.

A human can see that after the first `x` which falsifies the condition there's no point in trying all the larger values, but Haskell will try those anyway, and get stuck on a kind of infinite loop.

This is because, in the general case, the condition could become true once again, e.g.

```
[3 * x | x <- [1 ..], 3 * x < 20 || x == 1000000 ]
```

In general it is *undecidable* to detect whether there are no more solutions, so Haskell, like any other programming language, can not opt to stop after the last solution.

If you want the list to stop after the first value which does not satisfy the filtering condition, use `takeWhile`:

```
takeWhile (< 20) [3 * x | x <- [1 ..]]
```

Comment: Great explanation! Though out of curiosity, do you know if there is a way to do this all within the list comprehension?

Comment: @DavLin: Not exactly. Sometimes you can use a lazy number type like `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`, so if you have a condition like `genericLength someList < (10 :: Nat)`, it can return even if `someList` is infinite by examining only 10 elements; whereas `length` won’t halt if `someList` is infinite, because its result `Int` is strict. In this case, even using a lazy number type, the list would never end: the comprehension keeps producing elements, and they keep being filtered out. So you really want `takeWhile` on the output or an upper bound on the input, like ``[1 .. (20 `div` 3) + 1]``.

Comment: @DavLin See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319771/takewhile-within-a-list-comprehension/29321355#29321355) but briefly put, no you can't do that inside the list comprehension. The hack I wrote there as an answer is a kind of a joke, which technically makes it possible at the cost of greatly increasing the complexity of the code, enabling a bunch of extensions, requiring some custom libraries, and using a weird semantics. Don't ever use that.